# Making large toolbars like the iPod app

Tags: iphone

I am trying to create a toolbar programatically (rather than via IB) very similar to the toolbar featured in the iPhone app:

[image]

Currently I've been experimenting with the `UIToolbar` class, but I'm not sure how (and if?) you can make the toolbar buttons centrally aligned and large like that in the iPod app.

Additionally, regardless of size, the gradient/reflection artwork never correctly respects the size and is stuck as if the object is the default smaller size.

If this cannot be done with a standard `UIToolbar`, I guess I need to create my own view. In this case, can the reflection/gradient be created programmatically or will it require some clever alpha tranparency Photoshopped artwork?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is:

- create MyToolbar.h and MyToolbar.m : MyToolbar can be inherited from UIToobar
- create an empty xib named MyToolbar.xib
- In Interface Builder, add a new UIToolBar with "IB->Tools->Library"
- With "IB->Tools->Inspector", change the class identity to "MyToolbar"

Now, you can customize your toolbar with IB or with xCode as you want.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not doing this via IB. I've edited my question to make this clearer.